# Spring specify multiple transactional managers for @Transactional annotation

Tags: spring, rollback, transactional

I'm writing some JUNIT tests and I want to be able to rollback transactions against multiple databases. At the moment I have the following annotations in use to make sure the databases are in the same state before and after the tests were run.

```
@Transactional(transactionManager = "someTransactionManager")
@Rollback
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Are you running the tests on external databases? Do you have them configured for XA transactions? Usually for unit test purposes I use an embedded DB (like H2 or HSQL) and create all the tables there, in a single DataSource. If you can show more of your tests/usages/configuration, it might make things more clear.

Comment: Traditionaly you would go for JTA setup for that. See https://spring.io/blog/2011/08/15/configuring-spring-and-jta-without-full-java-ee/